# Фильтровать из переменной jquery

Tags: jquery

В аякс приходит ответ от сервера html, но в виде строки и мне нужно выбрать определенный тег, как правильно это сделать? пробовал через filter, но не получилось.

```
var html = $.parseHTML();
html = $(html);
html = $(html).filter('#product-category');
console.log(html);
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, расскажите более подробно почему не получилось(ошибка или ещё что-то) и что ещё пробовали.

Comment: `success: function(content){ $(content).find("#tag").... }`